# SharePoint 2013 WebPart error in Microsoft.Sharepoint dll (version 15.900)!

Tags: sharepoint

I create webpart project and have an error in microsoft.sharepoint.dll version 15.900 !!!

My sharepoint server is stand-alone and my webpart project is stand box.

Error:

```
Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Correlation ID: 7e71979d-0624-c00a-0000-09fb3f08ee0e.
```

code:

```
 using (var site = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var list = web.Lists["MyList"];
                var result = list.Items.Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();
                spGridView.DataSource = result;
                spGridView.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

.ASCX file:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1.ascx.cs" Inherits="t5.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1" %>

<SharePoint:SPGridView id="spGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="Navy" Font-Bold="true" />
  <Columns>
    <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Employee">
      <headerstyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </SharePoint:SPBoundField>

  </Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SPGridView in sandbox solutions. Try to use GridView control or create your own and inherit it from GridView.